# Can't commit changes while changing the code in github

Tags: github

I have a problem that I cant commit changes during editing the scripts in github please somebody help me

[image: click to view the screenshot]

Comment: please show us the file you are trying to commit, or try committing with another file and see what happens

Comment: It seems like you haven't added or edited any files. please make your screenshot so we can see everything

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means you are not a [collaborator](https://docs.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-user-account/inviting-collaborators-to-a-personal-repository) in the [`pamekasancode/Code-Forces-Algorithm`](https://github.com/pamekasancode/Code-Forces-Algorithm): you can not contribute directly to the `main`/`master` branch of that repository.

You should be able to commit if you select the second option

"[`Create a new branch for this commit and start a pull request`](https://docs.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/creating-a-pull-request)".

See as illustration "[How to make your first contribution in GitHub without using Command line](https://medium.com/@haimantikamitra/how-to-make-your-first-contribution-in-github-without-any-commands-cb8fc48fc48f)" from **[Haimantika Mitra](https://twitter.com/haimantikam)**

[image: make new pr]

Comment: Thanks, now I understand what should i do

Answer (score 1):

you cannot commit directly to master branch, you'll need to first create a branch commit your code there and then submit a pull request (PR) before you code can be merged to the master